# Using similarity matrix to measure diversity of a group

Tags: group-differences, distance, entropy, similarities, euclidean

I wish to measure the "diversity" of a group of objects. Right now I'm using Euclidean distance to compute the similarity matrix between all the objects in the group.

I'm searching for a measure of this diversity to decide if replacing an element of this matrix with a new one will make the group more or less homogeneous. I wish to end up the most heterogeneous group.

Of course, I'm open to another approaches if I'm looking at this from the wrong angle.

Bonus points if it's computationally efficient.

Comment: Can you describe your data, both the concepts behind what is being measured, and also the kinds of variables?

Comment: Knowing euclidean distances between points automatically means knowing the multivariate variance in these data. Does variance look right to you as a measure of diversity?

Comment: Is it something in that line http://azimuth.mathforge.org/discussion/1311/quantum-entropy-for-biodiversity/ ?